# iPhone not getting notified after being in the background for minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, uilocalnotification

I have a location app. When the user select an address he/she can set a radius before the chosen address to get alerted.
The local notification is set upped in the `didEnterRegion:`
The thing that I noticed is if the user sets the alert and close the app and passes more than 15 minutes, no notification appears.
Some time when the user press the lock or home button the notification trigger.
and if it is less than that everything works fine.

The app has two views. The intro view, where the user can choose an address and the second view with the map.

Do you guys have any idea what might be happening?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UILocalNotification?. If you do, you have 2 consider 2 scenarios in your AppDelegate.m:

1) The app was closed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //local notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if ([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"your key"] isEqual:@"your object"])
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

2: The app is still alive.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
   // same as before
}
```

Comment: sorry but I think you are mistaken. didFinishWithOptions means "Tells the delegate that the launch process is almost done and the app is almost ready to run." I am getting the notification but only when I press the home button or the wake button is that the sound plays.